# Trying to solve long equation using Wolfram|Alpha. It doesn' t understand.

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to solve this equation: `Solve[(sin(c) sec(t) (2 a b sin(c - t) + x sin(t)) + cos(c) (x - a b cos(c)))^2/a^2 + (sin(c) (x - a b cos(c)) - cos(c) (2 a b sec(t) sin(c - t) + x tan(t)))^2/(a^2 (1 - b^2)) == 1, x]`, using Wolfram|Alpha. I made it shorter using W|A, but when I try to solve it it says: "Wolfram|Alpha doesn't understand your query. Showing instead result for query: **Solve sin**"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's probably too long for Wolfram|Alpha. If you are interested only in the solution for $x$, try to simplify the expression. For instance, use $m_1=\sin(c)\sec(t)$, $m_2=2ab\sin(c-t)$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, maybe it's too long for WolframAlpha. Not just the input but also the output, which is the following (computed in Mathematica):

[image]

Comment: I suppose that you took as input what was given to WA without changing $sin(t)$ to $Sin[t]$ and so on.

Comment: You are right...my fault. I will fix as soon as possible.

Comment: I fixed the syntax. Now the output is correct. Still very long.

Comment: It is just a question of grouping terms first. We juast face a quadratic equation in $x$.